# CompletionProvider Intellisense in extension working only for specific symbol ':' not for dot symbol '.'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions, code-completion

Working on vscode extension to provide Intellisense with the help of CompletionProvider API. 
I have added registerCompletionItemProvider with the triggerCharacters  as ':' it works but when i change the  triggerCharacters to dot '.' the Intellisense stops showing.
Do i have to make some extra setting change or register my trigger characters somewhere to get the Intellisense in my json document.

Another issue related to CompletionProvider what i'm facing is I'm not getting any intellisense inside a string marked in quotes "", I have checked few other people having the same issue, they are able to resolve it by adding  "editor.quickSuggestions": {"strings": true} in setting.json. 
I tried the same but no luck !! Can somebody help me what I'm missing here.

Comment: You should include some code in your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).